# Where to put complex operations in an MVC framework?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, model-view-controller, architecture

Let's say I have a method RegisterUser() which contains more code than just inserting a record into a database. For example, maybe there are roles, location data, etc. Or I have a method SendInboxMessage() which sends an inbox message to a user for a CMS site for example... Keeping in mind that SendInboxMessage does more than just interact with an "inbox" table. It needs to interact with user objects, message objects, inbox folder objects etc. Again, just giving an example here of something complex with a lot of objects.

Where would things like this go for a traditional MVC?

(Note: This is not language specific. Looking for a more broad answer here)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where would things like this go for a traditional MVC?

MVC is a way of structuring a presentation layer of an application.
But I guess you are talking about classical business logic.
This should be part of a business layer, not of the presentation layer.
The business logic you described would usally go into a domain service. 
A domain service is basically just a stateless object which methods are exposed to the presentation layer by an interface (a contract).
The methods of a domain service are usually dependent on data repositories or other domain services and describe comlpex transactional operations.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Do you have any examples or literature where I can read more about this? E.g. what is meant by "exposing methods by a contract"

Comment: No problem. Martin Fowler has some nice articles about the different GUI architecture patterns on his homepage: 
http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html .

Comment: "Exposing methods by a contract" means that
1: The domain service methods need to be reachable by the presentation layer.
2: The method calls from the presentation layer have to address a (technical) interface and might have to meet specific pre- and postconditions.

Comment: A detailed description of the service layer concept can be found here: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html